# How to write the set defined by an indicator function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

For a set $A$ we can write its indicator function $\mathbf{1}_A$ as

$$\mathbf{1}_A(x) :=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x \in A\\
0 & \text{if } x \notin A
\end{cases}$$

Is there any agreed-upon notation for the reverse, the set characterized by the function $f$?

Comment: You  will also see $\chi_A$ for $1_A$ (Greek chi for "characteristic function").

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it would be easy enough to write the set as $\big\{x \,|\, f(x)=1\big\}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular notation, as far as I know. Usually you would just write $$f^{-1}(\{1\}).$$

Comment: Or sometimes you can write $f^{-1}(1)$. A common abuse of notation.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not sure what you're referring to by $f$.)

If predicate $\mathbf 1_A(x)$ is defined in terms of set $A$, it implicitly has two parameters, set $A$ and element $x$. In that case, the predicate you're looking for could be expressed $\mathbf 1_{A^\prime}(x)$ (in other words, just pass in the complement of $A$ as a parameter to predicate $\mathbf 1$).

If membership of $A$ is determined by the predicate, in other words, if $A=\left\{x:\mathbf1_A(x)\right\}$, then predicate $\mathbf 1_A(x)$ is implicitly a boolean function, and the predicate determining membership to the complement of $A$ could just be written $\lnot \mathbf 1_A(x)$ or $\overline{\mathbf 1_A(x)}$, in other words, $A^\prime=\left\{x:\lnot \mathbf 1_A(x)\right\}$.